# Create a slider with a transition similar to that on the MetaLabs page? (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Wondering if anyone knew how to achieve the effect presented in the slider here:

http://metalabdesign.com/

I can make a slider by lining up images and sliding them over, but how would I go about making that expanding/fading transition with jQuery library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to change the size, position and opacity of the element.

```
$(element).animate({
    opacity:0,
    left: '-=30',
    top: '-=30',
    width: 630,
    height:330
}, 400);
```